# Meaning of "you are sharing my share of with"

Tags: meaning, poetry

There's a poem that used this phrase and the line approximately sounds like that:

> I think of [...] the heart you are sharing **my share of** with the American air.

I fail to understand the point of the phrase "my share of" in the middle of this phrase. The line "I think of the heart you are sharing with the America" makes sense for a poem, but I'm not sure about the function of that "my share of". My share of what?

L.E. This is the poem: [Frank O'Hara - Now that I am in Madrid I can think](https://readalittlepoetry.com/2010/11/23/now-that-i-am-in-madrid-i-can-think-by-frank-ohara/)

Comment: You need to provide a link if possible. You might be misquoting that verse.

Comment: @fev Sure, this is the poem: https://readalittlepoetry.com/2010/11/23/now-that-i-am-in-madrid-i-can-think-by-frank-ohara/

Comment: Yes, you **are** misquoting: it's "with the American air".

Comment: @fev I've thought that the noun is not relevant for the structure of the phrase that I'm trying to understand. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: It ain't the best line in the world.

Comment: “the heart you are sharing my piece of with the American air” might make it more palatable to you. Honestly though this poetry is lamentable, why would you read such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

> ... the heart you are sharing *my share of [the heart]*...

The author has a share in the heart of the person he is thinking of. That person is "sharing" that share of heart with the American air. It's a lyric way of stating the close bond the author has with that person.

Comment: I see, thank you for explanation! If you don't mind, I have another doubt regarding a line from this poem, specifically: "and in Toledo the olive groves’ soft blue **look** at the hills with silver like glasses like an old lady’s hair". Could you tell me please what's the reason for the verb *look* being written without a final *s*? Is it a simple lyric choice or am I misunderstand the phrase? Soft blue **looks** [...]

Comment: It may be that the author uses "groves'" (little forest) as a collective noun. So he may refer to the trees looking at the hills. But it is poetry, and grammar is not a pattern poetry always follows...

Answer (score 1):

> I think of you
>
> and the continents brilliant and arid
>
> and the slender heart you are sharing my share of with the American air.

You should understand this as

> I think of you
>
> and the continents brilliant and arid
>
> and the slender heart {[that] you are sharing {my share of [your heart]}} with the air that is in America [where you are at the moment].